# Automatically switch to Chromecast audio

Tags: google-play-music, chromecast

I have a group of Chromecast audio devices setup in my house. Is there a way for my phone to automatically start casting when I connect to the same WiFi network?

Ideally I want to be able to listen to music through my headphones on the commute home and when I arrive it switches automatically to the Chromecast audio devices.

Is this something that has been done before or shall I start coding?

Comment: Do you have root access?

Comment: Yes and i'm running CyanogenMod 13 if that's any help

Comment: It might be possible with Tasker.

Comment: Would it be possible with IF by IFTT?

Answer (score 0):

Right, after some research it's certainly possible with Tasker combined with the (premium) Autocast app or AutoInput (beta feature of tasker.)

**AutoInput + Tasker Method**

*(according to some, can sometimes be unresponsive, but it's free.)*

```
Profile - State - Net - Wifi Connected - input your SSID Task 
Action - Launch App - (music app) 
Wait 5 seconds (to allow app to fully load)
AutoInput Action - Select cast button 
AutoInput Action - Select chromecast
AutoInput Action - Press play
```